# Build NetworkX graph from pandas data frame which ignores NaN edges

Tags: pandas, graph, networkx, nan

I am trying to make a network graph from a pandas dataframe (see picture 'Example of dataframe') with a node for each 'directors' whose size is proportional to 'Score'. Each node would have either no link if 'Score_pair' == NaN or else a link whose thickness would be proportional to 'Score_pair'. (See example in the picture 'Expected result'). As an example to the dataframe, I saved it as a dictionary which you can find at the end of this post.

[image: Expected result]

[image: Example of dataframe]

I have been trying to use from_pandas_edgelist function but I am not sure how to handle the NaN. Should I split in different plot lines or is there a way to do this simply?

Library versions: pandas 1.3.4, networkX 2.8.4, pyvis 0.3.1

```
# Load pandas as networks graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(top_N_directors_graph, source='directors0',target='directors1',edge_attr='Score_pair')

# Create vis network
net = Network(notebook=True)
# Load the networkx graph
net.from_nx(G)
```

I have also tried the following:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(top_N_directors_graph, source='directors0',target='directors1',edge_attr='Score_pair')

#graph esthetic parameters
max_node_size = 20000
max_edge_width = 100

#extract edges weights, normalize them and define their width in the graph
weights = np.array([G[u][v]['Score_pair'] for u,v in G.edges()])
weights = (weights - np.min(weights)) / (np.max(weights)-np.min(weights))
weights *= max_edge_width

#extract scores over the whole corpus, normalize them and define their width in the graph
nodes_scores = top_N_directors_graph['Score']
nodes_size = np.array(nodes_scores)
nodes_size = (nodes_size - np.min(nodes_size)) / (np.max(nodes_size) - np.min(nodes_size))
nodes_size *= max_node_size
                        
# Generate layout for visualization
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))

# Visualize graph components
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.5, edge_color="m") # width = weights
#nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=nodes_size, node_color="#210070", alpha=0.9)
label_options = {"ec": "k", "fc": "white", "alpha": 0.7}
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=18, bbox=label_options)
```

which at least gives a result but not the one expected. When running the commented line, I obtain the following error.

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=nodes_size, node_color="#210070", alpha=0.9)


Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/rw/vbdhblbj0w719my3yr4ln6bm0000gn/T/ipykernel_10830/527045054.py in <module>
     21 # Visualize graph components
     22 nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.5, edge_color="m") # width = weights
---> 23 nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=nodes_size, node_color="#210070", alpha=0.9)
     24 label_options = {"ec": "k", "fc": "white", "alpha": 0.7}
     25 nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=18, bbox=label_options)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py in draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist, node_size, node_color, node_shape, alpha, cmap, vmin, vmax, ax, linewidths, edgecolors, label, margins)
    431         alpha = None
    432 
--> 433     node_collection = ax.scatter(
    434         xy[:, 0],
    435         xy[:, 1],

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1410     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1411         if data is None:
-> 1412             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1413 
   1414         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, **kwargs)
   4369                 (not np.issubdtype(s.dtype, np.floating) and
   4370                  not np.issubdtype(s.dtype, np.integer))):
-> 4371             raise ValueError(
   4372                 "s must be a scalar, "
   4373                 "or float array-like with the same size as x and y")

ValueError: s must be a scalar, or float array-like with the same size as x and y
```

Thank you in advance!

[image: Result]

Reproducible example:

```
{'directors': {0: 'Joe Pinkerton', 1: 'Charles L. Gaskill', 2: 'Tony To', 3: 'Moirangthem Maniram', 4: 'Raul Barcelona', 5: 'Don DuPree', 6: 'Michael Gershman', 7: 'Fabien Pruvot', 8: 'Jean-Jacques Andrien', 9: 'Callie Crossley', 10: 'Thomas Ott', 11: 'Thomas Ott', 12: 'Sam Pollard', 13: 'Henry Hampton', 14: 'Henry Hampton', 15: 'Henry Hampton', 16: 'Henry Hampton', 17: 'Madison D. Lacy', 18: 'Madison D. Lacy', 19: 'Madison D. Lacy', 20: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 21: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 22: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 23: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 24: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller'}, 'Score': {0: 2.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 5.0, 3: 7.0, 4: 8.0, 5: 9.0, 6: 10.0, 7: 13.0, 8: 14.0, 9: 15.0, 10: 15.0, 11: 15.0, 12: 15.0, 13: 15.0, 14: 15.0, 15: 15.0, 16: 15.0, 17: 15.0, 18: 15.0, 19: 15.0, 20: 15.0, 21: 15.0, 22: 15.0, 23: 15.0, 24: 15.0}, 'director_pair': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: ('Callie Crossley', 'Sam Pollard'), 10: ('Thomas Ott', 'Callie Crossley'), 11: ('Thomas Ott', 'Sam Pollard'), 12: nan, 13: ('Henry Hampton', 'Callie Crossley'), 14: ('Henry Hampton', 'Madison D. Lacy'), 15: ('Henry Hampton', 'Sam Pollard'), 16: ('Henry Hampton', 'Thomas Ott'), 17: ('Madison D. Lacy', 'Callie Crossley'), 18: ('Madison D. Lacy', 'Sam Pollard'), 19: ('Madison D. Lacy', 'Thomas Ott'), 20: ('Terry Kay Rockefeller', 'Callie Crossley'), 21: ('Terry Kay Rockefeller', 'Henry Hampton'), 22: ('Terry Kay Rockefeller', 'Madison D. Lacy'), 23: ('Terry Kay Rockefeller', 'Sam Pollard'), 24: ('Terry Kay Rockefeller', 'Thomas Ott')}, 'Score_pair': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: 15.0, 10: 15.0, 11: 15.0, 12: nan, 13: 15.0, 14: 15.0, 15: 15.0, 16: 15.0, 17: 15.0, 18: 15.0, 19: 15.0, 20: 15.0, 21: 15.0, 22: 15.0, 23: 15.0, 24: 15.0}, 'directors0': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: 'Callie Crossley', 10: 'Thomas Ott', 11: 'Thomas Ott', 12: nan, 13: 'Henry Hampton', 14: 'Henry Hampton', 15: 'Henry Hampton', 16: 'Henry Hampton', 17: 'Madison D. Lacy', 18: 'Madison D. Lacy', 19: 'Madison D. Lacy', 20: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 21: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 22: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 23: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 24: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller'}, 'directors1': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: 'Sam Pollard', 10: 'Callie Crossley', 11: 'Sam Pollard', 12: nan, 13: 'Callie Crossley', 14: 'Madison D. Lacy', 15: 'Sam Pollard', 16: 'Thomas Ott', 17: 'Callie Crossley', 18: 'Sam Pollard', 19: 'Thomas Ott', 20: 'Callie Crossley', 21: 'Henry Hampton', 22: 'Madison D. Lacy', 23: 'Sam Pollard', 24: 'Thomas Ott'}}
```

For ease of reading:

```
{'directors': {0: 'Joe Pinkerton', 
    1: 'Charles L. Gaskill', 
    2: 'Tony To', 
    3: 'Moirangthem Maniram', 
    4: 'Raul Barcelona', 
    5: 'Don DuPree', 
    6: 'Michael Gershman', 
    7: 'Fabien Pruvot', 
    8: 'Jean-Jacques Andrien', 
    9: 'Callie Crossley', 
    10: 'Thomas Ott', 
    11: 'Thomas Ott', 
    12: 'Sam Pollard', 
    13: 'Henry Hampton', 
    14: 'Henry Hampton', 
    15: 'Henry Hampton', 
    16: 'Henry Hampton', 
    17: 'Madison D. Lacy', 
    18: 'Madison D. Lacy', 
    19: 'Madison D. Lacy', 
    20: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 
    21: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 
    22: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 
    23: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 
    24: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller'}, 
'Score': {0: 2.0, 
    1: 4.0, 
    2: 5.0, 
    3: 7.0, 
    4: 8.0, 
    5: 9.0, 
    6: 10.0, 
    7: 13.0, 
    8: 14.0, 
    9: 15.0, 
    10: 15.0, 
    11: 15.0, 
    12: 15.0, 
    13: 15.0, 
    14: 15.0, 
    15: 15.0, 
    16: 15.0, 
    17: 15.0, 
    18: 15.0, 
    19: 15.0, 
    20: 15.0, 
    21: 15.0, 
    22: 15.0, 
    23: 15.0, 
    24: 15.0}, 
'director_pair': {0: nan, 
    1: nan, 
    2: nan, 
    3: nan, 
    4: nan, 
    5: nan, 
    6: nan, 
    7: nan, 
    8: nan, 
    9: ('Callie Crossley', 'Sam Pollard'), 
    10: ('Thomas Ott', 'Callie Crossley'), 
    11: ('Thomas Ott', 'Sam Pollard'), 
    12: nan, 
    13: ('Henry Hampton', 'Callie Crossley'), 
    14: ('Henry Hampton', 'Madison D. Lacy'), 
    15: ('Henry Hampton', 'Sam Pollard'), 
    16: ('Henry Hampton', 'Thomas Ott'), 
    17: ('Madison D. Lacy', 'Callie Crossley'), 
    18: ('Madison D. Lacy', 'Sam Pollard'), 
    19: ('Madison D. Lacy', 'Thomas Ott'), 
    20: ('Terry Kay Rockefeller', 'Callie Crossley'), 
    21: ('Terry Kay Rockefeller', 'Henry Hampton'), 
    22: ('Terry Kay Rockefeller', 'Madison D. Lacy'), 
    23: ('Terry Kay Rockefeller', 'Sam Pollard'), 
    24: ('Terry Kay Rockefeller', 'Thomas Ott')}, 
'Score_pair': {0: nan, 
    1: nan, 
    2: nan, 
    3: nan, 
    4: nan, 
    5: nan, 
    6: nan, 
    7: nan, 
    8: nan, 
    9: 15.0, 
    10: 15.0, 
    11: 15.0, 
    12: nan, 
    13: 15.0, 
    14: 15.0, 
    15: 15.0, 
    16: 15.0, 
    17: 15.0, 
    18: 15.0, 
    19: 15.0, 
    20: 15.0, 
    21: 15.0, 
    22: 15.0, 
    23: 15.0, 
    24: 15.0}, 
'directors0': {0: nan, 
    1: nan, 
    2: nan, 
    3: nan, 
    4: nan, 
    5: nan, 
    6: nan, 
    7: nan, 
    8: nan, 
    9: 'Callie Crossley', 
    10: 'Thomas Ott', 
    11: 'Thomas Ott', 
    12: nan, 
    13: 'Henry Hampton', 
    14: 'Henry Hampton', 
    15: 'Henry Hampton', 
    16: 'Henry Hampton', 
    17: 'Madison D. Lacy', 
    18: 'Madison D. Lacy', 
    19: 'Madison D. Lacy', 
    20: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 
    21: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 
    22: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 
    23: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller', 
    24: 'Terry Kay Rockefeller'}, 
'directors1': {0: nan, 
    1: nan, 
    2: nan, 
    3: nan, 
    4: nan, 
    5: nan, 
    6: nan, 
    7: nan, 
    8: nan, 
    9: 'Sam Pollard', 
    10: 'Callie Crossley', 
    11: 'Sam Pollard', 
    12: nan, 
    13: 'Callie Crossley', 
    14: 'Madison D. Lacy', 
    15: 'Sam Pollard', 
    16: 'Thomas Ott', 
    17: 'Callie Crossley', 
    18: 'Sam Pollard', 
    19: 'Thomas Ott', 
    20: 'Callie Crossley', 
    21: 'Henry Hampton', 
    22: 'Madison D. Lacy', 
    23: 'Sam Pollard', 
    24: 'Thomas Ott'
    }
}
```

Comment: 1- please provide a minimal reproducible example, 2- the full error, 3- the libraries versions

Comment: My bad, I am new to Stack overflow. I added an example at the end of my post. The full error can be found in the picture.

Comment: I think networkx get confused because of the `nan` values. By the way you probably mean `np.nan`, after als oimporting numpy. Having just the directors edges in a list of tuples worked for me. Let's say your dictionary is called `data` and then we have `G=nx.empty_graph();edges = [v for v in data['director_pair'].values() if v is not np.nan];
G.add_edges_from(edges)`. Not sure about the drawing though

Answer (score 0):

Here my own answer:

```
def draw_bubble_graph(df_score, df_pair_score, feature, N):
# df_score: dataframe with score of independent features
# df_pair_score: dataframe with score of paired features
# feature: string name of column in dataframe to process 'directors', 'actor_name', 'genre'
# N: number of feature points to include

# Remove empty entries:
df_score = df_score.drop(index=df_score[df_score[feature] == ''].index,axis=0)

top_N = df_score.sort_values(by='Score')[0:N]
ls_top = top_N[feature].tolist()
df_pair_score = df_pair_score.rename({feature: feature +'_pair', 'Score':'Score_pair'}, axis = 1)

# Create a merged dataframe where we have only collaborations which include top features
df = top_N.merge(df_pair_score.rename({feature: feature +'_pair', 'Score':'Score_pair'}, axis = 1),how='left',left_on=feature, right_on= feature +'0')
top_N_graph = df[df[feature +'1'].isin(df[feature])]
#del df

# Contains only top collaboration
top_N_graph.head()

# Complete with top individuals without collaboration
top_N_graph = top_N.merge(top_N_graph,how='left',on=[feature,'Score'])
top_N_graph.sample(5)

# Create network graph: 

#graph esthetic parameters
max_node_size = 1000
max_edge_width = 100

# normalize scores and define their width in the graph
nodes_scores = top_N_graph.drop_duplicates(subset=feature)['Score']
nodes_size = np.array(nodes_scores)
nodes_size = ((nodes_size - np.min(nodes_size)) / (np.max(nodes_size)-np.min(nodes_size)) + 1 if np.max(nodes_size)!=np.min(nodes_size) else nodes_size/np.max(nodes_size))
nodes_size *= max_node_size

#Rescale edge weights: 
weights = top_N_graph['Score_pair'].dropna()
weights = ((weights - np.min(weights)) / (np.max(weights)-np.min(weights)) + 1 if np.max(weights)!=np.min(weights) else weights/np.max(weights))
#weights *= max_edge_width
top_N_graph['weight_edge'] = weights

# Create edge data:
edge_data = pd.DataFrame({'source' : top_N_graph[feature].tolist(),
                      'target' : top_N_graph[feature +'1'].tolist(),
                      'weight' : top_N_graph['weight_edge'].tolist()})

# Create node data:
node_data = pd.DataFrame({'name' : top_N_graph[feature].tolist(),
                      'score': top_N_graph['Score'].tolist()}).drop_duplicates(subset='name')


G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edge_data, 'source', 'target', True)
# Remove edges to NaN
G.remove_edges_from(list(zip(edge_data[edge_data['target'].isna()]['source'], edge_data[edge_data['target'].isna()]['target'])))
# Remove node NaN
if np.nan in G:
    G.remove_node(np.nan)
        

# Generate layout for visualization
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))


# Visualize graph components
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=nodes_size, node_color='crimson', alpha=0.9)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.5, edge_color="lightseagreen") # width = weights

label_options = {"ec": "k", "fc": "white", "alpha": 0.7}
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=18/20*10, bbox=label_options)

# Resize figure for label readibility
ax.margins(0.1, 0.05)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.axis("off")
plt.title("Impactful " + feature)

#plt.savefig('../output/network_sparse.png', dpi = 500)
plt.show()
```